# What is the the difference between the monotheism of Trinitarian Christianity and Judaism?

Tags: trinity, judaism, comparative-religion, monotheism

If both Judaism and Trinitariansm are monotheistic, Jesus being a jew, do both faiths have the same God?

If the word mono means one, single how can it be explained logically that 3 is 1 and 1 is  3?

Is God the source of fuzzy logic and numbers?

Comment: Judaism's monotheism is uni-personal, rather than tri-personal. This means that Trinitarian Christians like me would say it has many of the same flaws as Modalism, such as [God not being inherently loving, eternally Father, or eternally communicative](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/86903/6071).

Comment: Christians have never said that the number 1 is the number 3 or vice versa.

Comment: @curiousdannii. What does  tri of the words trinity and triune mean?

Comment: @AlexBalilo God is one, in the sense of one entity. He can be understood in 3 different parts. This [chart](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Shield-Trinity-Scutum-Fidei-English.svg) was very beneficial to me.

Comment: @Luke Note however that Trinitarians have opposed the term "part" to refer to the persons of the Trinity, as if they were each a third of God. Each has the fullness of God.

Comment: @curiousdannii as a Trinitarian myself (Catholic) yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Monotheism requires one God who, alone, is worshipped.
Judaism has but one God who, alone, is worshipped.
Christianity has but one God who, alone, is worshipped.

For ease of understanding, compare that with the Hindu triad. It requires three gods who are all worshipped equally. But a triad is not a trinity, for the Christian trinity requires one God.

Your question would benefit from elaboration because monotheism is monotheism is monotheism. You add a comment in the form of a second question, "If both Judaism and Trinitariansm are monotheistic, Jesus being a jew, do both faiths have the same God?" Jesus being a Jew has nothing to do with either question.

Both Judaism and Christianity are clear that there is only one true God, who alone is to be worshipped. If one group has a more complex understanding of the nature of deity than the other, that does not necessarily mean one group cannot be worshipping the same God as the other group. All sincere worshippers of the only true God grow in their understanding as they keep seeking to learn about and to please God. Some are at one level of understanding, others are at another. Knowing God is a matter of divine revelation that comes in degrees; it is not about head-knowledge, or having theological degrees. God sovereignly chooses to whom, and to what extent, he reveals himself. That accounts for an awful lot of clashing theological beliefs about the nature of the one true God.

EDIT in response to your edit, "If the word mono means one, single how can it be explained logically that 3 is 1 and 1 is 3? Is God the source of fuzzy logic and numbers?"

Regarding Deuteronomy 6:4, this commentary notes:

> "In Heb. shem'ayisrael y'hovah'eloheynuy'hovah echad = "Hear , O Israel, Jehovah [the Self and ever existing One), our Elohim, is one Jehovah."

> one. Heb. 'ehad - a compound unity (Latin unus), one made up of others [Then gives 8 O.T. examples...] It is not yahid, which is (Latin) unicus, unique - a single, or only one [and gives 12 OT examples of that...]." (The Companion Bible notes p247)

Comment on this verse is worth quoting from another source:

> "Some have thought there is here a plain intimation of the trinity of persons in the unity of the Godhead; for here is the name of God three times, and yet all declared to be one." (Matthew Henry Commentary, p192, 3rd column).

***The Jewish and Christian God is not a numeric 'one'***, so the sooner people stop thinking that, the sooner they will see the logic of the trinity doctrine. It never was a case of 1 + 1 + 1 = 1 as scoffers love to say. Given that 1 x 1 x 1 = 1, numeracy should not be used to disagree with the trinity doctrine. ***It's not about numbers. It's about complex relationship within the Godhead***. I hope that helps those who think the doctrine shows 'fuzzy logic', when it's fallible human logic that's the problem. Grasping the complexity of the one God, who alone is to be worshipped (as both Jews as trinitarian Christians adamantly maintain) requires divine revelation. That comes supremely in seeing just who Jesus the Messiah is. **When Jewish people grasp that, they realise Christians have the same God as the God of the Shema of Deuteronomy 6:4.**

Comment: Up-voted +1. God's sovereignty and his own revelation of himself are essential to knowing the mystery of Deity.

Comment: @Anne. If it is not about numbers , what does tri of the word trinity mean. How do you come up with your conclusion that mono is actually triune? What does tri of the words triune mean?

Comment: @Alex Balilo  It's about simplicity and complexity. The concept of there being but one God, who alone is to be worshipped, seems simple until we note God's self-revelation throughout the scriptures and how complex the Almighty is. If we ignore his self-revelation and stick to a simple numeric concept of God, we'll get hung up on one versus three (numerically). It's not about one versus three. Whilst one is not three numerically, spiritually it is entirely something else! Don't get hung up on numbers. Enlarge the vision as per the scriptures.

Comment: @Anne. Your comment and answer seem like circular reasoning to me.

Comment: @Anne, I have to tell you, I always look forward to reading one of your answers. Every reply is couched in language appropriate for that answer, betraying your desire to have God’s word permeate our thinking organically, and for us to think like the author thinks.

Comment: @Alex Balilo, might I recommend a softer, more malleable approach to this topic, one that says “I’m not going to insist upon THE answer, but I’m going to allow the passage at hand to speak to me.” That’s what I did. I found Elohim conversing in Genesis… I found the Lamb worshipped with the same liturgy as God in Rev 4&5; I found Jesus feeding the Israelites in a “desert place” with supernatural food in the Gospels… I found Jesus saying “before Abraham was, I am”. And for all of these moments, I find others, showing equally clearly that there is a separation between God and Jesus,…

Comment: …especially (but not exclusively) when Jesus was on earth. How can both be true? I don’t know, it’s a mystery! But I don’t try to say the one is false because the other is true… Use or lose. 

Answer (score 0):

> do both faiths have the same God ?

No, because the inner [moral character](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/83300) of these two Gods is completely different from one another. While *formally* or *officially* revering the Old Covenant and its deity, orthodox Christianity practically reinterprets the meaning and intention behind the actions and behavior of the Old Testament God (itself distinct from the post-biblical Jewish God), so as to render it more attuned with the One preached by its Founder.

The Old Testament, along with the Talmud, and the works of various post-Talmudic rabbis, such as [Maimonides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) and [Nachmanides](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nachmanides), are in the public domain, in plain English; one can easily contrast and compare them with Christian morality, if one so desires.

Of course, non-orthodox forms of Christianity, such as [Gnosticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnosticism), who [repudiated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcionism) the Old Testament and its deity, did indeed exist; but they were simply an excuse to indulge in otherwise pagan habits, forbidden, sometimes under penalty of death, by the Mosaic Covenant, as can be glimpsed from various surviving ancient patristic works, contemporary with the aforementioned movement, such as [Irenaeus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irenaeus)' *[Against Heresies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Against_Heresies_(Irenaeus))* and [Augustine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustine_of_Hippo)'s anti-Gnostic [writings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustine_of_Hippo_bibliography), among others.

Generally speaking, Christianity chose to reinterpret old pre-Christian myths, legends, faiths, and religions, rather than brutally abolish them (which is why all Christian bibles still have an Old Testament); seeing Gnosticism's failed experiment, one can, in retrospect, better understand why this more diplomatic path was also much wiser and more successful than its alternate.

> What is the the difference between Jewish monotheism and Trinitarian monotheism ?

Apart from reinterpreting Jewish morality, Christianity also reinterpreted Jewish theology; thus, the basic notion of divine unity was reinterpreted through the lens of passages such as Genesis 2:24 (quoted in Matthew 19:5-6, Mark 10:8, 1 Corinthians 6:16, Ephesians 5:31), especially in light of Genesis 1:26-27, this theme of familial unity being also echoed by John 10:30, with respect to Christ and His Father.

As I wrote [elsewhere](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/83441):

> <sub>Let us recall that, while Adam (meaning *Man*) may not have been the only human in the Bible, he certainly is the only one to have borne the name of our entire species in his own person; with all of this in mind, let us now adduce the following reasoning: Just as Adam's (*Man's*) humanity does not infringe upon that of the beings descended from his own flesh and blood (Genesis 2:23), despite his being the only person in the entire Scripture to have ever borne the name *Man* as his own personal name, in virtue of his being the one father of all mankind, so also the divinity of the one God and Father does not necessarily deter other possible divine persons (personifying His various divine attributes, as Eve did with Adam's) from possibly sharing in the same divinity; notice also how the very next verse (Genesis 2:24) perfectly mirrors or resembles Christ's own idea of family unity, expressed in John 10:30.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that I'm a man, a programmer and a musician, while only being one person. God has three aspects to himself while still being only one person or God. Christians are no more or less mono-theist than Jews or Muslims.

Comment: In spite of the potential to have holes picked in your answer regarding the ‘single personhood’ of God, I still think it’s a great illustration and, contextually, you are not making a theological statement but offering a useful way to view a particular concept. 

Comment: @NeilMeyer love this!

Comment: This description of God does sound a lot like modalism however. Analogies for God are difficult and imperfect. It's important to Trinitarians that God not actually be just one person, because the persons relate and communicate with each other in ways that we as single persons in multiple roles cannot.

Comment: This is not a good analogy. God is 1 nature, 3 persons.